# Recurrence relation running time

Tags: recursion, math, time-complexity, recurrence

im having troubles to analyze Recurrence relation running time that has 2 recurrences.
now its with this relation, and i need to find it running time:

```
T(1)=1, T(n)= T(2n/3)+t(n/4)+n
```

tried several ways, didnt work out.
how do i solve this and what is the correct way to approach it?
thank u in advance.

Comment: Please show what you tried that "didnt work out", and what the problem was.

Comment: This looks like a purely math question, and should be posted to https://math.stackexchange.com if you are looking for an answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter ive tried to solve it through master theorm, and also with recursive tree. both didnt work out for me..

Comment: Are you after a sample of recursive function which would implement this?

Comment: @ChaudPain im after this recurrence running time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method